# Unconstrained generic constant when using const function to compute generic constant

Tags: generics, rust

In my journey to type-level programming, I am encountering a rather odd error, unconstrained generic constant that I am failing to understand.

Here is a minimal example:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]


const fn func1<T, U>() -> bool { true } // some logic
const fn func2<T, U>() -> bool { false } // some logic

// provide access to the bool constants for different types
trait CompareResult {
    const R1: bool;
    const R2: bool;
}


struct CompareResultHolder<const R1: bool, const R2: bool>();

impl<const R1: bool, const R2: bool> CompareResult for CompareResultHolder<R1, R2> {
    const R1: bool = R1;
    const R2: bool = R2;
}

trait CompareTypeList {
    type Compare<T>: CompareResult;
}


impl<T> CompareTypeList for T {
    type Compare<U> = CompareResultHolder<{func1::<T, U>()}, {func2::<T, U>()}>;
}
```

([Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51966a7d0179c6f9427a12ccc1673bad))

I'm trying to provide some boolean values computed from operations on types, and having a trait allowing to get access to those values easily. The idea is that I can then access them with

```rust
<<T as CompareTypeList>::Compare<U> as CompareResult>::R1
```

The hint that the compiler provides does not quite help either:

"help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [(); {func2::<T, U>()}]:`".

I've read that this error can occur when an impl can cause conflicting implementations by itself, but here I have no idea how this would occur as I am simply trying to compute the constant values.

Any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to compile by moving the generic around the `CompareTypeList` trait rather than just on the `Compare` associated type. It might be possible to pull the same trick without making that change (though I couldn't find the right syntax for it).

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]


const fn func1<T, U>() -> bool { true } // some logic
const fn func2<T, U>() -> bool { false } // some logic

// provide access to the bool constants for different types
trait CompareResult {
    const R1: bool;
    const R2: bool;
}


struct CompareResultHolder<const R1: bool, const R2: bool>;

impl<const R1: bool, const R2: bool> CompareResult for CompareResultHolder<R1, R2> {
    const R1: bool = R1;
    const R2: bool = R2;
}

trait CompareTypeList<T> {
    type Compare: CompareResult;
}


impl<T, U> CompareTypeList<U> for T
where
    [(); func1::<T, U>() as usize]:,
    [(); func2::<T, U>() as usize]:,
{
    type Compare = CompareResultHolder<{func1::<T, U>()}, {func2::<T, U>()}>;
}
```

The `where [(); {expr}]:` syntax is really strange, I found it in the [design doc](https://hackmd.io/OZG_XiLFRs2Xmw5s39jRzA?view) for `generic_const_exprs` ([tracking issue with link to doc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560)).

AFAICT, it abuses the array type to check whether a const expression is "well formed", which seems to basically be translated to "can be used as an array capacity", which meant I had to cast to `usize`.

Clearly, this feature is very very unfinished, so *caveat emptor* (even the compiler gives a warning to this effect). I full expect (and sincerely hope) that this syntax is either unneeded or changed before stablisation.

Comment: I got this syntax at some point, but I had to switch to having the generic in the output type: this is used for type-level programming, and having the generic in the output type allow the trait to act like a function, where as having it in the trait itself make it act like a generic type/function. I had to go away from this solution because it's incompatible with the rest of the code (I could have mentionned that in the original post, sorry)

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique I don't think that can ever work. The compiler's saying that it needs you to provide a bound that involves both `T` and `U`, so somewhere you need to be able to write a bound for both simultaneously. It's unfortunate, since we can see that this particular bound is trivially true for all types, but apparently the compiler cannot see that.

Comment: I do not understand why does the generics require a bound (Maybe I am missunderstanding "bound" here) ? The implementation should be for any types `T` and `U`, I do not see what I need to justify about them

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique I'm not an author of this feature, and it's very incomplete both in implementation and documentation. I'm not sure many people will be able to tell you *why* the compiler is saying it needs those bounds. The fact is that the compiler, as currently implemented, does apparently require those bounds. Like I said, I can see that these bounds are trivial for all types, but the current implementation in the compiler apparently cannot.

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique If you really want to understand (and especially if you want to help with the implementation), go find the compiler team on the official forums and/or zulip. I they they are the people responsible for implementing this feature.

Comment: I might want to get invested in this. Thanks !